# Row dendrogram ordering gave index of wrong length in heatmap.2 upon passing distfun

Tags: r, heatmap

With I am trying to plot with this code:

```
library(gplots)
set.seed(1)
irisn  <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 30), ]
dat    <- irisn[,1:4]
clust_meth <-"ward.D2" 
dist_metrics <- "pearson"
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat), 
              dendrogram="none",
              scale="row",
              Colv=F,
              Rowv=T,
              key=T,
              trace="none",
              hclustfun = function(x) hclust(x, method=clust_meth),
              distfun = function(x) as.dist(1-cor(x, method=dist_metrics))
            )
```

Why it breaks at `distfun` giving this error message:

```
Error in heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat), dendrogram = "none", scale = "row",  : 
  row dendrogram ordering gave index of wrong length
```

How can I resolve this?